# VB.Net hide specific gridview columns based on dropdown text selection

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, hide

Using Visual Studio and VB.net I have a gridview populated with data and based on the text values in a dropdown I would like to hide certain columns and unhide as appropriate.

The dropdown is populated via sql with a list of subjects (English, Maths Science etc..)

The grid contains columns including three columns KS2 English, KS2 Maths and KS2 Average.

When English is picked from the dropdown I would like to hide the KS2 Maths and KS2 Average columns.

When Maths is picked I'd like to hide the KS2 English and KS2 Average columns.

Finally if any other subject is selected I'd like to hide the KS2 English and KS2 Maths columns.

I've already populated the gridview ok with data that is updated based on the subject in the dropdown, but I'm not sure what I need to do to start getting specific about what columns are displayed based on the selection.

Here is a screenshot which should make it clear what I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

It used for add handler

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

        If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then

            AddHandler CType(e.Control, ComboBox).SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf LastColumnComboSelectionChanged

        End If

    End Sub
```

Its used for visible false the columns

```
Private Sub LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Visible = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Visible = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Visible = True

    If sender.SelectedItem = "Maths" Then
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns(4).Visible = False
    ElseIf sender.SelectedItem = "English" Then
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns(4).Visible = False
    ElseIf sender.SelectedItem = "others" Then
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns(4).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I've implemented this within my project and replaced in the appropriate controls for the gridview, dropdown and column positions, but I'm getting errors advising that types `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs` and `ComboBox` are not defined.

Comment: do you add datagridviewcomboxcolumn in your datagridview. And you are wroking in winforms or web

Comment: Thanks @SATSON. I've added a screenshot which will hopefully make things clearer. 

I have a separate dropdownlist and gridview control in a webform.

Comment: Thanks @SATSON, your suggestions pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it. Wrote the following procedure on page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GvStudentDetails.Columns(17).Visible = False
    GvStudentDetails.Columns(18).Visible = False
End Sub
```

And the following select case statement within my dropdown select procedure:

```
Protected Sub DdlSubject_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DdlSubject.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case strSubject
        Case "English"
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(16).Visible = True
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(17).Visible = False
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(18).Visible = False
        Case "Mathematics"
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(16).Visible = False
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(17).Visible = True
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(18).Visible = False
        Case Else
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(16).Visible = False
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(17).Visible = False
            GvStudentDetails.Columns(18).Visible = True
    End Select
End Sub
```